# cordova android build error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'

Tags: cordova, iconic

I am trying to build cordova android and the build is failing with the following error.
Error :   platforms\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:35: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

The version of Node and Cordova 
- node: 6.10.3
- cordova : 6.5.0
- android build tools : 26

```
#The dependencies in build.gradle

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26.+"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}


#The project.properties file

target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2+
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-mfp/live-build-extras.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-mfp-push/live-build-extras.gradle
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+
cordova.system.library.5=com.android.support:support-v4:26.+
cordova.system.library.6=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+

Error :   platforms\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:35: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

We are stuck on this. Please help if there are changes in the build.gradle or project properties.

Comment: Based on couple of stackoverflow solutions we tried upgrading to 28 too but getting another error 

com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy.class